# How can I get String in String[]?

Tags: android

```
String[] string = {getResourse().getString(R.string.girl), getResourse().getString(R.string.boy), getResourse().getString(R.string.child)};// Why is this code not working
```

And I tried do like this

```
String[] string = {getString(R.string.girk)....};
```

And also I tried do like

```
String[] string = {R.string.girl...};
```

Everything is not working, or it is impossible?

Comment: Have you tried -> 
String[] strings = new String[] {getResourse().getString(R.string.girl)}; ?

Comment: @TiagoDávila Yes, just tried. But This is not the solution of problem

Comment: @DeveloperChingis then in that case what is the problem?? How you want it

Comment: @TiagoDávila I have tried you option String[] strings = new String[] {getResourse().getString(R.string.girl)};.But the app crashes

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh I have tried the option String[] strings = new String[] {getResourse().getString(R.string.girl)};.But the app crashes

Comment: please, provide stacktrace.

Comment: Why is this code not working? Because you need to write `getResource()`

Comment: @TiagoDávila FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.kazlingo.a1.kazlingo, PID: 15069
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.kazlingo.a1.kazlingo/com.kazlingo.a1.kazlingo.Methods.Acquaintance}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()

Comment: @Stanojkovic I tried String[] string = {getResourse().getString(R.string.girl)....} But not working

Comment: You have typo in `getResourse()`! Write `getResource()`.

Comment: @Stanojkovic like it ?getResourse(getString(R.string.gilr))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, R.string.girl is int type.

If you really want to define it programatically like below,

```
String[] string2 = {getString(R.string.app_name)};
```

You should define it when your Activity/fragment's context is avaliable. For example, you can define it inside onCreate method but it is impossible to define it as a global variable (Because getString is the method of Context class).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like in this example.

[image]

For more info https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray